# N prefix and parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC MyProc ( @FullName NVARCHAR(200) = NULL )
    AS --.............
```

When I call this proc as `exec MyProc 'Some english text'` it works good.

But if call it as `exec MyProc 'Русский текст'` that is using Russian alphabet, it doesn't work properly.

And the call `exec MyProc N'Русский текст'` works good again.

I have a client application and... I need to add  N prefix to parameters? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The N would only be needed (manually) if you are concatenating a string in the .net code. 
It's automatic if you declare a [SQLParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) as nvarchar: the framework takes care of it for you.

So your client code is *incorrect* and opens you up to *SQL injection*

Anyway, the N says that the string literal is unicode.

Comment: <<So your client code is incorrect and opens you up to SQL injection>> why?

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: Search for SQL Injection and parametrisation: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SQL+Injection+and+parametrisation

Comment: How to protect my procedure from sql injection?

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: as per the links, "parametrisation"

Answer (score 0):

`N` means National language character set also well known as Unicode.

See on Microsoft KB: [You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530/en-gb)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of client application do you use?

- if it is .Net - just specify that parameter has Unicode type.
- If it is OLEDB/ADO - the same thing, param must be marked as unicode, and pass wchar_t instead of char

**Update**
Sample from msdn (pay attention to NVarChar):

```
yourCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value = "toasters";
```

And please avoid SQL injection ;)